# Countdown timer not stopping at 0

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

For some reason, my timer does not stop when the time reaches 0. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8d5LLeoa/1/). Here is the constructor for the countdown timer I made:

```
var Timer = function(opts) {
  var self = this;

  self.opts     = opts || {};
  self.element  = opts.element || null;
  self.minutes  = opts.minutes || 0;
  self.seconds  = opts.seconds || 30;

  self.start = function() {
    self.interval = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
  };

  self.stop = function() {
    clearInterval(self.interval);
  };

  function countDown() {
    if (self.minutes == 0 && self.seconds == 0) {
      self.stop();
    }

    self.seconds--;

    if (self.seconds <= 0) {
      self.seconds = 59;
      self.minutes--;
    }

    if (self.seconds <= 9) { self.seconds = '0' + self.seconds; }

    self.element.textContent = self.minutes + ' : ' + self.seconds;
  }
};
```

and here is my usage:

HTML:

```
<div id="timer"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var myTimer = new Timer({
  minutes: 0,
  seconds: 10,
  element: document.querySelector('#timer')
});

myTimer.start();
```

Comment: Your minutes and seconds never reaches 0, and seconds is also a string that never goes to 0. This is the offending line `if (self.minutes == 0 && self.seconds == 0)`.

Comment: You're skipping over `0` seconds because you set it to `59` when you get there.

Comment: Just an idea, why don't you have a method of `Timer` that outputs a zero-padded string of `self.seconds` so that you don't have to do that string cast. I think that would accomplish the same thing without causing the problems that might come from changing the whole variable to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your countdown function to

```
function countDown() {
    self.seconds--; //Changed Line
    if (self.minutes == 0 && self.seconds == 0) {
      self.stop();
    }

    if (self.seconds < 0) { //Changed Condition. Not include 0
      self.seconds = 59;
      self.minutes--;
    }

    if (self.seconds <= 9) { self.seconds = '0' + self.seconds; }

    self.element.textContent = self.minutes + ' : ' + self.seconds;
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8d5LLeoa/3/

Answer (score 2):

You just need to rearrange your countdown function a bit. It will never be zero when it hits your code that checks for a zero value. The code below works.

```
function countDown() {

self.seconds--;
      self.element.textContent = self.minutes + ' : ' + self.seconds;

if (self.minutes === 0 && self.seconds === 0) {
  self.stop();
  return;    
}

if (self.seconds <= 0) {
  self.seconds = 59;
  self.minutes--;
}
if (self.seconds <= 9) { self.seconds = '0' + self.seconds; }
  }
};
```

Comment: I can only choose one answer, but I gave you an upvote!